# How to pass state data from custom hooks to react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have custom hook(`useFetch`) that takes URL as input and fetch data from that URL and returns data. I want to implement spinner (already made `Spinner` component ) on my other components and I tried by making state for the `isLoading` and `setIsLoading` of spinner. 
my custom hook code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    const useFetch = (url) => {
      const [dataArray, setData] = useState([]);
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
        try {
          const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const dataArray = await res.json();
            setData(dataArray.data);
          };
          fetchData();
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
      }, [url]);

      return dataArray;
    };

    export default useFetch;
```

This is the component that I want to implement spinner.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CONSTANTS from '../../constants/constants';
import CompanyLists from '../../components/company-lists/CompanyLists';
import Pagination from '../../components/pagination/Pagination';
import useFetch from '../../components/effects/use-fetch.effect';
import Spinner from '../../components/spinner/Spinner';
const CompanyListing = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const companies = useFetch(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`);

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <div style={userStyle}>
          {companies ? companies.map((company) => <CompanyLists key={company.id} {...company} />) : 'No companies'}
        </div>
        <Pagination props={companies} counter={counter} name="companies" setCounter={setCounter} />
        <Spinner />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
const userStyle = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(1, 1fr)',
  gridGap: '1rem',
};
export default CompanyListing;
```

Problem here is: How can I send those loading state from hook to `CompanyListing` component. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

I have other component that also calls same hook and I want them not to be broken. As I didn't mention on original question . 
My another case:

```
const jobsUrl = `${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/jobs?page=${counter}`;
  const jobs = useFetch(jobsUrl);
```

AND

```
const { city, company_name, company_id, department, description, job_type, position, posted_at, url } = useFetch(
    `${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/jobs/${id}`
  );
```

How can I destructure in these two cases ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need anything special here. Just return the `isLoading` state with the `dataArray` from the `useFetch` hook.

As mentioned from the edit you need the `useFetch` to be more reusable and return data in different formats depending on the API response, hence the state should be initialized as null.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
  // it is best to initialize the state as null because response.data
  // may be an object or an array depending on the API response

   const [data, setData] = useState(null);

   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
     try {
        const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const value = await res.json();

        setData(value.data);
        };
          fetchData();
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
   }, [url]);

   return {data, isLoading};
};

export default useFetch;
```

In the components you want to use the custom hook, you can destructure
the value for `data` and `isLoading` but to futher destructure values from the returned data we have to check if `data` is `null`

```js
// destructure the values
const {data, isLoading} = useFetch(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`);

// in this case data will be an array based on your API response
// please make sure to check data.length before trying to loop over
// and render the content, for example

return (
 <div>
  {
    data.length && data.map(company => (
      <CompanyLists key={company.id} {...company} />
    ));
  }
 </div>

)
```

For the second case where you will be fetching data using `` useFetch(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/jobs/${id}`); `` you have to check if the returned data is not null before destructuring further. For example:

```js
const { data, isLoading } = useFetch(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/jobs/${id}`);

if (isLoading) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

if (data) {
  const { 
      city, 
      company_name, 
      company_id, 
      department, 
      description,
      job_type, position, posted_at, url } = data;


  return (
    // your jsx code
    // for example
    <h3>{company_name}</h3>
    <p>{department}</p>

  )
}
```

Comment: I have another component where I am calling `useFetch`  like `const { name, description, jobs, known_to_sponsor_visa } = useFetch(\`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies/${id}\`);` what can be done to make it work as well ?

Comment: Can you share the response returned from your API route `${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies/${id}`?

Comment: Hello Click (https://autechjobs-backend-api-de6mkdm5gq-uc.a.run.app/api/companies/4) for API url.

Comment: In this case `response.data` is an object, which means `useFetch` hook will work for this case, but when destructuring properties from  the returned value from `useFetch` hook depending upon the component and how it renders the data you might get and error saying `cannot read property 'someproperty' of undefined` or null. To make `useFetch` reusable for all the cases and be able to destructure the properties it needs some refactor to be done. I will be updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `isLoading` as well from the hook.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    const useFetch = (url) => {
      const [dataArray, setData] = useState([]);
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
        try {
          const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const dataArray = await res.json();
            setData(dataArray.data);
          };
          fetchData();
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
      }, [url]);

      return {dataArray, isLoading};
    };

export default useFetch;
```

And use this in your component like this

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CONSTANTS from '../../constants/constants';
import CompanyLists from '../../components/company-lists/CompanyLists';
import Pagination from '../../components/pagination/Pagination';
import useFetch from '../../components/effects/use-fetch.effect';
import Spinner from '../../components/spinner/Spinner';
const CompanyListing = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const {dataArray: companies, isLoading} = useFetch(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`);

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <div style={userStyle}>
          {companies ? companies.map((company) => <CompanyLists key={company.id} {...company} />) : 'No companies'}
        </div>
        <Pagination props={companies} counter={counter} name="companies" setCounter={setCounter} />
        {isLoading && <Spinner />}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
const userStyle = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(1, 1fr)',
  gridGap: '1rem',
};
export default CompanyListing;
```

Comment: I have another component where I am calling `useFetch`  like `const { name, description, jobs, known_to_sponsor_visa } = useFetch(\`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies/${id}\`);` what can be done to make it work as well ?

Answer (score 1):

From your custom hook you can return both like

```
   return {companies: dataArray, isLoading };
```

And destruct both

```
const {companies, isLoading} = useFetch(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`);
```

Comment: What if I am returning not only companies from hook ? As i am returning Jobs as well . This solution won't work.

Comment: I have another component where I am calling `useFetch`  like `const { name, description, jobs, known_to_sponsor_visa } = useFetch(\`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies/${id}\`);` what can be done to make it work as well ?

Comment: Please update your question to refer your current issue and code for us to be able to be more helpful

Comment: Hello @Hagai . Question is updated below EDIT section. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you try to do with the customHook for achieve that? How does it is look now when it suppose to return `name, description, jobs, known_to_sponsor_visa`? They are all in array?object?

Answer (score 1):

First, you might need to change your `useFetch` effect a bit to update `isLoading` correctly. Then you could return both `dataArray` and `isLoading` :

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [dataArray, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const dataArray = await res.json();
        setData(dataArray.data);
      };
      await fetchData();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [url]);

  return [dataArray, isLoading];
};

export default useFetch;
```

And use it like the following :

```js
const [companies, isLoading] = useFetch(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`);
```

Comment: `Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`

Comment: I have another component where I am calling `useFetch`  like `const { name, description, jobs, known_to_sponsor_visa } = useFetch(\`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies/${id}\`);` what can be done to make it work as well ?